# Hide Search Bar in VSCode

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

How to hide and show `Search Bar` in VS Code ? I would like to hide `Search Bar` to show Workspace.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+B since  it looks like it is in your side bar.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. Ctrl+B is hiding the whole Side Bar. But I need to hide and show only Search Bar. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if I understood what you want to do, but you can just use the key combinations to switch from one panel to another. Using the same shortcuts twice will reveal/hide the whole sidebar. For your question, this could be the most useful:

- `Ctrl + Shift + E` File Explorer
- `Ctrl + Shift + F` Finds text in all files
- `Ctrl + Shift + H` Search and replace in all files
- `Ctrl + B` Hide/reveal the whole sidebar

Also, you can check all shortcuts by clicking `View` or `Edit` in the menu bar.

For the people that may came here looking for how to remove the **top** search bar: right click on it > uncheck `Command center`; right click in title bar and check it again to restore.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+B on Windows, Cmd+B on macOS